# flutter build apk Errors

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I encountered a problem when using `flutter build apk` to export APK file and install on an android device. How to fix these errors, please?

[image]

[image]

And when I open this project in Android Studio to do `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX` I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code under `android/gradle.properties` to migrate the project to AndroidX.

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true
```